# OAUTH login with Google doesn't set cookie but adds hash string to url instead, using Nuxt3 with Superbase

Tags: google-oauth, nuxtjs3

I am new to Superbase and Nuxt3. I am trying to login with OAUTH using the following code. It works in Safari but not in Chrome.

Any pointers would be highly appreciated!

```
<script setup>
  const user = useSupabaseUser();
  const email = ref('');
  const errorMsg = ref('');
  const { auth } = useSupabaseAuthClient();

  const userLogin = async () => {
    try {
      const { error } = await auth.signInWithOAuth({
          provider: 'google',
      });
      email.value = '';
      if (error) throw error;
    } catch (error) {
      errorMsg.value = error.message;
      setTimeout(() => {
        errorMsg.value = '';
      }, 3000);
    }
  };
  watchEffect(() => {
    if (user.value) {
      return navigateTo('/');
    }
  });
</script>
```

This works fine in Safari but in Google the cookies aren't being set but tokens appear to be sent to the url after a hash, like this:
localhost:3000/login#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkdGcElQZzh6STZZc1g3WDEiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.Z4LrbnWiGWnrO3LPhr_qGn_n6xdF8IxF6Ph2Om08BUI&expires_in=3600&provider_token=ya29.a0AbVbY6MjLn-CkGchYHlTZNANSycx_KBX_hvn15vcFfWzt8YIYm-hVULZrJlvgQvgKAOZSJgL7yWGGrv5tAKVVa4Vz1_BrbyweVBxcuo9VugPMcmsZ5rIzMi6Y0cyYqSv7l_4Ego_2JTuCzuQzou8wWWdrNd5aCgYKAUESARISFQFWKvPlwWnRxEGBhw0xo88JrMid5Q0163&refresh_token=hXyshxmvB4kTd0XSgsCv2Q&token_type=bearer

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread on github which describes the bug and the solution here:
https://github.com/supabase/gotrue-js/issues/455#issuecomment-1649505404

Add this to the overrides section of your package.json:

```
"@supabase/supabase-js": {
  "@supabase/gotrue-js": "2.43.1"
}
```

}